# Помогите оптимизировать код (время выполнения более 2 сек.) Python

Tags: python

Задача:

Условия

Каждый пароль должен состоять из четного количества символов, и при этом первая половина пароля должна быть «анаграммно меньше» второй его половины. Теперь Василию нужен алгоритм, проверяющий, удовлетворяет ли придуманный пароль заданному условию.
Вам дано n пар строк одинаковой длины (каждая строка – половина пароля).

Строка s считается анаграммно меньше строки t, если существуют строка s' и строка t' такие что:

```
    s' получается из s перестановкой букв
    t' получается из t перестановкой букв
    s' лексикографически меньше, чем t'
```

Для каждой пары строк si, ti определите правда ли, что si анаграммно меньше чем ti.

Формат входных данных

В первой строке задано целое число n - число пар строк в тесте (1 < n < 100).

В следующих 3n строках содержатся описания пар строк. Каждое описание состоит из трех последовательных строк. В первой строке каждого описания дана длина строк m_i (1 < m_i < 100), затем в следующих двух строках записаны строки  s_i, t_i длины m_i, состоящие из строчных латинских букв.

Формат выходных данных

Для каждой пары строк из входных данных, выведите в i-й строке Yes, если строка s_i анаграммно меньше строки t_i. Иначе выведите No.

Собственно говоря код:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations
#Получаем исходные данные
list_1 = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    list_1.append([int(input()), input(), input()])
#Удаляем лишние элементы
for item in list_1:
    item.pop(0)
#Определяем условия для нахождения анаграммы
#Строка s считается анаграммно меньше строки t,
#если существуют строка s' и строка t' такие что:
for item in list_1:
    #s' получается из s перестановкой букв
    #t' получается из t перестановкой букв
    s_1, s_2 = ''.join(sorted(item[0])), ''.join(sorted(item[1]))
    #s' лексикографически меньше, чем t'
    e, f = min(permutations(item[0])), max(permutations(item[1]))

    if Counter(s_1) == Counter(item[0]) and Counter(s_2) == Counter(item[1]) and e < f:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Код вроде работает, но при больших объемах данных выходит за рамки отведенного времени на выполнение.

Comment: для чего вы используете permutations? генерите кучу ненужных данных, чтобы получить одну единственную строку, которую можно получить простой сортировкой

Comment: затупил, причем после подсказки понимаю, что очень жестко, с permutations  - искал ту самую строку t` которая больше s`. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортируйте первую строку по возрастанию, а вторую по убыванию, и сравните результаты.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/720811)

Comment: Как это не является? Всё, что нужно, в ответе дано.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
results = []
for i in range(N):
    n = int(input())
    s = input()
    t = input()
    if str(sorted(s)) < str(sorted(t, reverse=True)):
        results.append("Yes")
    else:
        results.append("No")
for i in range(N):
    print(results[i])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]